# Dual sort based on condition within a groupby

Tags: pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

[EDIT] Changed df size to 1k and provided piecemeal code for expected result.

Have the following `df`:

```py
import random
random.seed(1234)
sz = 1000
typ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sub_typ = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
ifs = ['A', 'D']
col_sort = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=sz)
col_val = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=sz)

df = pd.DataFrame({'typ': random.choices(typ, k=sz),
              'sub_typ': random.choices(sub_typ, k=sz),
              'col_if': random.choices(ifs, k=sz),
              'col_sort': col_sort,
              'value': col_val})
```

Would like to `sort` within `groupby` of [typ] and [sub_typ] fields, such that it sorts [col_sort] field in ascending order if `[col_if] == 'A'` and in descending order if `[col_if] == 'D'` and pick up the first 3 values of the sorted dataframe, in one line of code.

Expected result is like `df_result` below:

```py
df_A = df[df.col_if == 'A']

df_D = df[df.col_if == 'D']

df_A_sorted_3 = df_A.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: 
                    x.sort_values('col_sort', ascending=True)).\
                    groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort']).head(3)

df_D_sorted_3 = df_D.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: 
                    x.sort_values('col_sort', ascending=False)).\
                    groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort']).head(3)

df_result = pd.concat([df_A_sorted_3, df_D_sorted_3]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Tried:

`df.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col_sort', ascending=True) 
                        if x.col_if == 'A' else x.sort_values('col_sort', 
                        ascending=False)).groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort']).head(3)`

...but it gives the error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Comment: Kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting per groups is same like sorting by multiple columns, but if need same output is necessary `kind='mergesort'`.

So for improve performance I suggest  NOT sorting per groups in `groupby`:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
sz = 1000
typ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sub_typ = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
ifs = ['A', 'D']
col_sort = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=sz)
col_val = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=sz)

df = pd.DataFrame({'typ': np.random.choice(typ, sz),
              'sub_typ': np.random.choice(sub_typ, sz),
              'col_if': np.random.choice(ifs, sz),
              'col_sort': col_sort,
              'value': col_val})
# print (df)

df_A = df[df.col_if == 'A']
df_D = df[df.col_if == 'D']
```

---

```
df_A_sorted_3 = (df_A.sort_values(['typ', 'sub_typ','col_sort'])
                     .groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort'])
                     .head(3))
df_D_sorted_3 = (df_D.sort_values(['typ', 'sub_typ','col_sort'], ascending=[True, True, False])
                     .groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort'])
                     .head(3))

df_result = pd.concat([df_A_sorted_3, df_D_sorted_3]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_result)
    typ sub_typ col_if  col_sort  value
0     a      s1      A         0    709
1     a      s1      A         0    710
2     a      s1      A         0    801
3     a      s1      A         1    542
4     a      s1      A         1    557
..   ..     ...    ...       ...    ...
646   c      s4      D         1    555
647   c      s4      D         1    233
648   c      s4      D         0    501
649   c      s4      D         0    436
650   c      s4      D         0    695

[651 rows x 5 columns]
```

Compare outputs:

```
df_A_sorted_3 = df_A.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: 
                    x.sort_values('col_sort', ascending=True, kind='mergesort')).\
                    groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort']).head(3)

df_D_sorted_3 = df_D.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: 
                    x.sort_values('col_sort', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')).\
                    groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort']).head(3)

df_result = pd.concat([df_A_sorted_3, df_D_sorted_3]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_result)
    typ sub_typ col_if  col_sort  value
0     a      s1      A         0    709
1     a      s1      A         0    710
2     a      s1      A         0    801
3     a      s1      A         1    542
4     a      s1      A         1    557
..   ..     ...    ...       ...    ...
646   c      s4      D         1    555
647   c      s4      D         1    233
648   c      s4      D         0    501
649   c      s4      D         0    436
650   c      s4      D         0    695

[651 rows x 5 columns]
```

EDIT: Possible, but slow:

```
def f(x):
    a = x[x.col_if == 'A'].sort_values('col_sort', ascending=True, kind='mergesort')
    d = x[x.col_if == 'D'].sort_values('col_sort', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
    return pd.concat([a,d], sort=False)

df_result = (df.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ','col_if'], as_index=False, group_keys=False)
               .apply(f)
               .groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ', 'col_sort', 'col_if'])
               .head(3))
print (df_result)
    typ sub_typ col_if  col_sort  value
242   a      s1      A         0    709
535   a      s1      A         0    710
589   a      s1      A         0    801
111   a      s1      A         1    542
209   a      s1      A         1    557
..   ..     ...    ...       ...    ...
39    c      s4      D         1    555
211   c      s4      D         1    233
13    c      s4      D         0    501
614   c      s4      D         0    436
658   c      s4      D         0    695

[651 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Got your point of sort first and then use groupby. Also noted kind=mergesort (didn't know that default was quicksort). Isn't there a better way to to split, sort, combine and re-group in one line of code (on df), instead of splitting into two dataframes (df_A and df_D) and pd.concat?

Comment: @reservoirinvest - From term of performance I think not. Another way should be like you want `Groupby` with `apply`, but here it is slowier.

Comment: my `groupby` with `apply` is not working. Is there something wrong in it?

Comment: @reservoirinvest - there is no filtration for `A, D` groups.

Comment: @reservoirinvest - Added solution to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that *col_if* should act as a "switch" to the sort order.

But note that each group (at least for your seeding of *random*) contains
**both** *A* and *D* in *col_sort* column, so your requirement is ambiguous.

One of possible solutions is to perform a "majority vote" in each group,
i.e. the sort order in particular group is to be ascending if there are
**more or equal** *A* values than *D*. Note that I arbitrarily chose the
ascending order in the "equal" case, maybe you should take the other option.

A doubtful point in your requirements (and hence the code) is that you
put *.head(3)* **after** the group processing.
This way you get first 3 rows from the **first group** only.
Maybe you want 3 initial rows from **each group**?
In this case *head(3)* should be inside the lambda function (as I wrote
below).

So change your code to:

```
df.groupby(['typ', 'sub_typ']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col_sort',
    ascending=(x.col_if.eq('A').sum() >= x.col_if.eq('D').sum())).head(3))
```

As you can see, the sort order can be expressed as a *bool* expression for
*ascending*, instead of 2 similar expressions differing only in *ascending*
parameter.